# How can we change the width and height of linear layout during run time in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Guyz... Plz help.. Give the proper code because i use most of examples of this problem and i m not able to solve this problem ...

Comment: you should post your best (or last) try so that we can try to see what's wrong in your special case. This question has many duplicates and might get closed.

Comment: Why? How? What have you done so far?

Comment: why do people even answer these posts? Might as well just ask someone to write his/her app for them...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can we change the width and height of linear layout during run time in android??

Step #1: Get the `LinearLayout`'s `LayoutParams` via [`getLayoutParams()`](http://goo.gl/hteWS). The actual class for these will depend on the `LinearLayout`'s parent.

Step #2: Modify values in the `LayoutParams`.

Step #3: Set the `LinearLayout`'s modified `LayoutParams` via [`setLayoutParams()`](http://goo.gl/zZURa).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the width/height dynamically you'd use `LayoutParams`

```
LinearLayour myLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
parentView.addView(myLayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```